# How can I join a Skype Public chat via links?

Tags: firefox, chromium, skype, protocol

In Windows, I can join a Skype Public chat by pasting a Skype chat link into a web browser's address bar (or clicking a link which contains that URI), but it doesn't work in my Ubuntu 10.04 using Skype 2.2.0.35.

The URI is generated by Skype from within a group chat via the command `/get uri`

Error messages from the following browsers are:

> # Firefox ... *the protocol (skype) isn't associated with any program*
>    # chromium-browser ... *just treats it as s google search argument*
>    # konqueror ... *Protocol not supported: skype*

How can I get these `skype:?chat&blob=...` links to work?

Edit: as I've mentioned in response to Tom Brossman's good comment, the main issue has now become: **which application** should be used for handling the `skype` protocol...  If it is Skype itself, what is the syntax? ... because `skype "%s"` does not process the protocol.

If someone has actually had success with the perl module `skype-action-handler` with a recent version of Linux Skype , it would be good to know.

Comment: Can you try manually registering Skype links by following this [Register Protocol](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#Linux) page from Mozilla? I think Skype was causing crashes and so it is no longer handled by default.

Comment: @Tom Brossman: Thanks, that has got me one step closer... I can now get Firefox to present a *Launch Applicatin* dialog, but the issue now becomes ***which application?*** Using `skype` as the app doesn't work other than to launch another instance of itself... I've tried installing this perl module [skype-action-handler](http://blogs.skype.com/linux/2006/08/making_skype_links_work.html) as detailed in the post by *thestudio53* ... Howerever, it doesn't work, as a dependency fails (Moose). It was not a trivial compile and I have no idea why and where it went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of [Net::DBus::Skype](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::DBus::Skype) and `skype-action-handler`. That was a tool to interface with DBUS to send commands to Skype via the DBUS API. The `skype-action-handler` does exactly what `Skype 4` will do via the `--call` argument

> skype --call "skype:echo123"
>
> skype-action-handler skype:echo123

Except I think I handled the URL format too which I don't think `--call` handles. I made this library and utility because back in 2008 the Skype for Linux was not nearly so polished. Originally, I believe it only used OSS even.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Evan, and a special thanks for your efforts with `skype-action-handler`.

Comment: FYI skype-action-handler doesn't work with `skype:?chat&...` URLs. It says: `Invalid argument! (format: skype:echo123?call)`

Answer (score 2):

To install skype-action-handler do:

```
sudo apt-get install cpanminus
sudo cpanm skype-action-handler
```

Update: Checked this suggestion myself. It almost works, but installs skype-simple-dialer instead. But that's irrelevant, because the latest version of Skype allows to select "Join a public chat" option above the contacts list and paste chat blob there.